# Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install` for installing glue 0.3 for Mac OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install glue 0.3 for OXS Mountain Lion and ran into this error after installing homebrew (Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install` You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root. However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at your own risk.) I got this error after the first step for installing glue 0.3 ($ sudo brew install jpeg). No idea how to fix this...please help!

Comment: The answer is in the message: don't use sudo. `brew install glue`

Comment: Thanks @VladtheImpala that seemed to work but when i run the second command ($ sudo pip install glue) it throws another error (sudo: pip: command not found)...Obviously, i'm hoping you could walk me through this lol.

Comment: Nvm i figured it out. Had to install pip using the default python package (sudo easy_install pip).

Comment: I had to execute `sudo chown -R $(whoami) [directory]` for every directory homebrew claimed it has no access to.

Answer (score 140):

```
sudo chown root /usr/local/bin/brew
```

Comment: simplest and best answer

Comment: This is not the recommended solution though. 
From [Answer from issue in github](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/9953)

These are your options:

(a) don't use sudo; adjust the permissions on directories in /usr/local accordingly. This is the recommended way to use Homebrew.

(b) chown the brew executable to root; and use sudo as you please. This is fine, but is not supported.

Comment: Don't be a fool. People don't have time to think over the stupid supported way.

Comment: Isn't it going to open everything to homebrew? And what's the step to get it back.

Answer (score 24):

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

Use the above command instead of changing the owner of `brew` to root.

This is the suggested method by the Owner of `homebrew` in https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/9953

Answer (score 8):

Answered by the developers here:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/9953

I solved it by NOT using sudo, and changing the permissions on whatever file it says cannot be accessed without sudo.

For example, I could not access /usr/local/Cellar, so I entered the following (as specified here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/3930)

```
sudo chmod g+w /usr/local/Cellar
sudo chgrp staff /usr/local/Cellar
```

Answer (score 5):

For **High Sierra macOS 10.13.3** or newer.

None of the solutions given here worked for me on this version. The only (and the best) **fix** is to **uninstall** brew and **install** it again with the following terminal commands. **Note you will lose your current kegs**, so you should get a list of the installed kegs, for reinstalling them after reinstalling brew as shown below under step 1. Actually, this was a good opportunity for me to get rid of those kegs that I am no longer using:

1. List your current kegs for reinstalling, those you wan't to keep:

   brew list
2. Uninstall brew:

   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
3. Reinstall brew:

   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
4. Optionally to prevent your usage being sent to Google Analytics (Update: Fortunately, now this has been stopped, so you may skip this step):

   brew analytics off
5. Finally reinstall your previous kegs from step 1 (or those you still want to use). Replace the text with the square brackets with the list, (i.e. `brew install sqlite heroku` ):

   brew install [list of kegs from step 1]

Comment: @aoh Thanks, I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 4):

I have updated my macos to sierra and `npm` stopped working. Below are the steps followed to fix them.

Uninstall Node and install it from brew and follow the below steps

```
sudo chmod g+w /usr/local/Cellar
sudo chgrp staff /usr/local/Cellar
sudo chown root /usr/local/bin/brew
sudo brew postinstall node
```

Answer (score 1):

This was helpful for me 
http://digitizor.com/fix-cowardly-refusing-sudo-error-brew/

As quoted in the text, you essentially have to change the user and group of brew to root and wheel respectively.